# SQLite: executeQuery() returns an empty result set

Tags: java, jdbc, sqlite

The following Java code returns an empty result set but the SQL shows that there is data in the table:

```
@Override
public List<Category> list() {
    List<Category> list = new ArrayList<>();

    if (!connection.isPresent()) {
        return list;
    }

    Connection con = connection.get();

    try {
        Statement stmnt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmnt.executeQuery(LIST_SQL);

        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("Got a record"); // DEBUG
            int id = rs.getInt(1);
            String description = rs.getString(2);
            list.add(new Category(id, description)); 
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        LOG.error("Error retrieving Category list", e);
        return list;
    }

    return list;
}
```

`LIST_SQL` is:

```
SELECT id, description FROM category
```

If I copy this query into `sqlite3` and execute it, several rows are returned.  `connection` works with other queries (but they are prepared statements and not an `executeQuery`).  There is no error.  "Got a record" is never printed.

Any ideas about what could be going wrong?

Comment: What is "connection.isPresent()" ?

Comment: I believe that:  int id = rs.getInt(1);  should be:  int id = rs.getInt("id");  and  String description = rs.getString(2);  should be:  String description = rs.getString("description");.

Comment: Oh...and don't forget to close stmnt under your catch statement:   finally { if (stmt != null) { stmt.close(); } }

Comment: @Berger connection is a java.util.Optional that contains the JDBC connection.  It works with other queries.

Comment: @DevilsHnd The program never gets to the SOP line marked DEBUG.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but did you ensure that "stmnt.executeQuery" gets executed at all ?

Comment: @Berger: Looks like it was a great question!  Investigating...

Comment: In that case then, what is:  Connection con = connection.get(); ? Try:  Statement stmnt = connection.createStatement();  instead.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys.  My `list()` method was never getting executed!  Why is another question.  Thanks for all your responses.

Comment: LOL...yup...helps if that gets fired :D

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you remembered to include the ";" in the LIST_SQL string. Semi-colon is required to end the query statement.

Comment: Putting a semicolon at the end of the string in LIST_SQL did not change the situation.  (I use the semicolon when I execute the query in sqlite3.)